# How to reuse the code developed using docx4j to POI 3.12 for parsing the xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Could someone help me...In redefining the code development using docx4j to POI.to get String value of the cell..getStringvlue(cell)

```
    try {
        STCellType type = cell.getT();
        String value    = cell.getV();

        if (cell.getF() != null && value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            /* cached formula result */
            return value;
        }

        if (type == null) {
            return value == null ? "" : value;

        } else {
            switch (type) {


            case S:

                return stringItems.get(Util.toInteger(value)).getT().getValue();

            case INLINE_STR:
                return cell.getIs().getT().getValue();

            case STR: /* STRING */
            case N:   /* NUMBER */
            case B:   /* BOOLEAN */
            case E:   /* ERROR */
            default:
                return Util.nullToEmpty(value);
            }
        }
```

IN POI , cell.getCelltype is deprecated.So iam facing some problem in conversion.

Comment: which problem exactly?

Comment: in getting cell value,and in  getting  inline cell value and sharedString value

Comment: if you don't know what type the cell is, then you need a switch statement (or if-else-if) to check the `cell.getCellType()` ([docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--) say that its not deprecated)

Comment: @Anu can you help us understand exact problem?

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache POI? Why not upgrade?

Comment: requirement to use only that specific version.....

Answer (score 1):

int getCellType() Deprecated in POI 3.15 so use

```
cell.getCellTypeEnum()


switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
  case S:

                return stringItems.get(Util.toInteger(value)).getT().getValue();

            case INLINE_STR:
                return cell.getIs().getT().getValue();

            case STR: /* STRING */
            case N:   /* NUMBER */
            case B:   /* BOOLEAN */
            case E:   /* ERROR */
            default:
                return Util.nullToEmpty(value);
}
```

Comment: in `poi 3.15` `getCellTypeEnum()` is deprecated as well

Comment: it not allowing me to use cell.getCellTypeEnum()